# Quiet vs Stop in Sidekiq

Tags: sidekiq

What's the difference between stoping workers vs 'quiet' them. In the web GUI I see both options but not sure what are the differences.

Also, whenever I stop all workers, do they stop gracefully meaning they are put on queue again or not?

Thanks.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

1. Quiet means don't fetch new jobs from Redis anymore.  Current jobs will continue to process indefinitely.
2. Stop means quiet immediately + force any jobs still processing after the `-t` timeout ([default](https://github.com/sidekiq/sidekiq/wiki/Deployment#overview): 25 seconds) to stop **and push those unfinished jobs back to Redis**.

Comment: `don't fetch new jobs from Redis anymore` what abouty when click QuietAll ?

Comment: QuietAll quiets ALL sidekiq processes, not just one.

Comment: Since Sidekiq v6, default timeout [was increased from 8'' to 25''](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/blob/master/Changes.md)

Comment: Then how to resume the quiet queues again?

Comment: Restart Sidekiq!

Comment: Hmm. Mike, we run multiple queues / workers. We quiet'ed a `cron`ed job, then restarted just the worker for that pod. It no longer shows as quiet -- but it doesn't seem to be doing any work, either.  Is there some additional `redis` state that we needed to clear?

Comment: @MikePerham- What is the meaning of indefinitely here..we are migrating to new cloud instance, we want to quiet the server, and once it finishes all jobs, it should not push new jobs, new server will take the new jobs. Will "quiet All" do the same?